# Can someone recommend a Program able to show and execute XQuery and XPath on a XML document?

Tags: software-recommendation, programming, xml

I'm searching for a program able to do Xpath and Xquery on XML, but I can't find one (I was using Oxygen XML editor on Windows 7 before). I was wondering if such a program exists for Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would look at one or more of the following packages:

```
apt-cache search xquery
```

Comment: I did it, but nothing came close of what I'm searching for.

Comment: Oxygen XML editor is available for Linux

Comment: I'm probably then just go back to that. I'm new on linux so I'm just searching to use as much as possible free program that are specially design for the OS (sorry if the question wasn't relevant).

Thanks for helping me!